# It also execute my else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

My if statement is true but it also executes my else statement

```
if ((request.readyState === 4) && (request.status === 200)) {
    var i = JSON.parse([request.responseText]);
    console.log(i);
} 
else {
    alert("no file");
}
```

Comment: Hardly believable. How do you think it does? Where does this code come from, in what environment is it executed, how was this snippet invoked?

Comment: Are you certain that your `if` statement is true? Are you seeing the output of `console.log(i)` in the console?

Comment: @Bergi my thoughts exactly

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you expected this snippet to be executed only once, but the `readyStateChange` event is fired multiple times. Try this:

```
if (request.readyState===4) {
    if (request.status===200) {
        var i = JSON.parse([request.responseText]);
        console.log(i);
    } else {
         alert("no file");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement is executed many times, some of them going to the "if" section and others to the "else". This is because is triggered every time the request status changes.

We'd need the entire code to see the way to solve it (not only the "if" fragment).